# Date compare within Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, case

I am still working on getting the data out exactly as I want it and it is almost there - one last question.

Here is my code:

```
      DECLARE @QA1 TABLE (SID varchar(7), FormID varchar(max), DateExam date, Present varchar(3))

      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(1, 'Form1', '20110101', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(2, 'Form1', '20110201', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(3, 'Form1', '20110301', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(4, 'Form1', '20110401', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(5, 'Form1', '20110122', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(1, 'Form2', '20110222', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(2, 'Form2', '20110322', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(3, 'Form2', '20110422', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(1, 'Form3', '20110128', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(1, 'Form4', '20110228', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(5, 'Form5', '20110328', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(5, 'Form6', '20111228', 'Yes')
      INSERT INTO @QA1 VALUES(4, 'Form2', '20111228', 'Yes')

      SELECT SID,
      ISNULL(MIN(CASE FormID WHEN 'Form1' THEN Present END), '') AS 'First Form',
      ISNULL(MIN(CASE FormID WHEN 'Form2' THEN isnull(CONVERT(varchar(12),DateExam,107),'') END), '')  as 'Date F2 Exam',
      ISNULL(MIN(CASE FormID WHEN 'Form2' THEN Present END), '') AS 'Second Form',
      ISNULL(MIN(CASE FormID WHEN 'Form4' THEN Present END), '') AS 'Fourth Form',
      ISNULL(MIN(CASE FormID WHEN 'Form5' THEN Present END), '') AS 'Fifth Form',
      ISNULL(MIN(CASE FormID WHEN 'Form6' THEN Present END), '') AS 'Sixth Form',

      ISNULL(MIN(CASE FormID WHEN 'Form3' THEN Present END), 

      MIN(CASE FormID WHEN 'Form2' THEN isnull(CONVERT(varchar(12),DateExam,107),'') END)

      ) AS 'Third Form'


      FROM @QA1


      GROUP BY SID
      ORDER BY SID
```

This gives me an output of this:

```
SID  First Form     Date F2 Exam     Second Form  Fourth Form  Fifth Form  Sixth Form  Third Form
1       Yes         Feb 22, 2011        Yes         Yes                                 Yes
2       Yes         Mar 22, 2011        Yes                                             Mar
3       Yes         Apr 22, 2011        Yes                                             Apr
4       Yes         Dec 28, 2011        Yes                                             Dec
5       Yes                                         Yes         Yes                     NULL
```

Which is very close to what I want but I actually want the Third Form Column to be either a Yes, Over Due or blank ('') with the overdue defined as if today is more than 34 days past the DateExam of Form2.

The last CASE statement successfully pulls the DateExam from Form2 but now I need to check whether it is overdue.  Do I need another CASE or a nested if-then-else to do the date adds ?  I know that to add my 34 days I need the DATEADD(day 34, DateExam) and I'll check it against GETDATE() but what form should the if-then-else statement be inside my CASE statement ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `Third Form` definition like this:

```
COALESCE(
  MIN(CASE FormID WHEN 'Form3' THEN Present END), 
  CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(D, MIN(CASE FormID WHEN 'Form2' THEN DateExam END), GETDATE()) > 34
      THEN 'Overdue'
    ELSE ''
  END
) AS 'Third Form'
```